# How can I include a PNG file as a numbered table in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, kable

I have a table generated by an external program as a PNG (or PDF) image and I'd like to include it as a numbered table in my Rmarkdown / Bookdown document.  The table is too complex to generate directly using kable or FlexTable etc.

I currently have

````
```{r table24, tidy=FALSE, echo=FALSE} 
kable(c(),caption="My table.")  
knitr::include_graphics("images/my-table.png") 
```
````

This works for HTML and DOC output, but not PDF (the image comes through, but it is not listed as a table).

There are online examples of including images within a table, but here the image IS the table.

Is there a better solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with LaTeX:

```
---
title: "Table"
header-includes:
- \usepackage {caption}
output:
  pdf_document
---

\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering
\caption{Big table which I have}  
\includegraphics{your_table.png}
\caption*{Put comments here if you want}
\end{table}
```

[image]

**P.S.:** here are some **useful** parameters, which can also help you in the future work:

```
\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm, angle = 10, keepaspectratio]{your_pic.png}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this generically in Rmarkdown, supporting HTML, PDF and doc output? Alternatively, is there a mechanism to include content conditionally, i.e. IF PDF do this ELSE IF HTML do that?

Comment: @Rob You can use both code chunks in your markdown. When you will knit to PDF - work my variant, when you will knit to html/doc - work yours. I see no problems. Why do you want to generate a redundant code? P.S. If i helped to you, you can accept my answer by putting a tick. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this

```
![caption](relative_path)
```

Comment: This only includes the captioned image. It does not make it a numbered table.